# How to leverage CNN for Portrait Image Segmentation in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, image-segmentation, cudnn

I will be needing a step-by-step process for Image Segmentation or If you can break down the problem into comprehensible and programmatically implementable modules that would also be a great help.

**Below Image is a snapshot of what needs to be done.**

[image: Extracted From Research Paper]

Here are some research papers that can help understand results I want.

1. [Automatic Portrait Segmentation for Image Stylization](http://xiaoyongshen.me/webpage_portrait/index.html)
2. [Automatically Remove Backgrounds From Images](https://news.developer.nvidia.com/ai-software-automatically-removes-the-background-from-images/)
3. [New Deep Learning Method Enhances Your Selfies](https://petapixel.com/2016/06/29/super-accurate-portrait-selection-masking-using-neural-networks/)

I have trained a tensor-flow model for custom object detection (apart from the 90 classes pre-trained COCO dataset model) but the problem is: TensorFlow does return the co-ordinates (bounding box) of the detected object, but we need the contour (outline) of the object.

^Considering that I know how to train CNN models with tensorflow, can you educate me how can I replicate the above research papers programatically? Like I know they collected a dataset of 1800 images and then transmuted that into 19000 images by augmentation but HOW can I prepare a dataset for training? what tool can I use to annotate images?

**Please help me implement the above research papers.
All I want is to extract a person from a photo - Portrait segmentation.**

Thanks a lot!